# Laravel Homestead Mailhog Error listening on socket: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:1025: bind: address already in use

Tags: homestead, mailhog

I am struggling to make MailHog work in my Laravel Homestead VM.

If I browse `http://localhost:8025/`, the web browser says it can't find it.

Then, in the command line, when executing `$ mailhog`, I get the following error:

> Error listening on socket: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:1025: bind: address
> already in use

Moreover, if I execute `$ mailhog --invite-jim` then I get:

> 2021/09/13 22:49:22 Using in-memory storage 2021/09/13 22:49:22 [SMTP]
> Binding to address: 0.0.0.0:1025 [HTTP] Binding to address:
> 0.0.0.0:8025 2021/09/13 22:49:22 Serving under http://0.0.0.0:8025/ 2021/09/13 22:49:22 [SMTP] Error listening on socket: listen tcp
> 0.0.0.0:1025: bind: address already in use

Here is my .env config file

**.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=reply@app.io
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Does anyone know or can shed some light how to make MailHog work?

Answer (score 1):

Mailhog web interface is clearly listening at the 8025 port. The `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` address may not work by default.

Take a look at both the `/etc/hosts` and `Homestead.yml` file

```
$ sudo vim /etc/hosts
$ vim Homestead.yml
```

Look for the address that Homestead is working on. In this case it's `192.168.10.10` or `192.168.56.56`

So now try
`http://192.168.10.10:8025` or `http://192.168.56.56:8025`

And it should be working now